# What value of $b$ makes the graph of $y^2 = x^3-x+b$ self-intersection?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, elliptic-curves

I was just exploring a little bit on Desmos, and was trying to figure out something somewhat interesting. I'm familiar that this is an elliptic curve, but ALL I know about them is that they are of the form $y^2=x^3+ax+b$. Nothing else, really....

So, here's what I'm thinking. Give $a$ an easy value, say $-1$, and let $b$ range over the reals. There is a specific value of $b$ for which the graph moves from one curve, to a curve and a closed circle-like figure. This specific value of $b$ makes the graph kind of.... "self-intersect" in a nice way. I've estimated it to be approximately $0.384900179459750$. I put this into WolframAlpha and it didn't recognize anything important. Is this constant important? Does it have a name? What's its value? Thanks.

Comment: You have put $a=-1$ in the title and $1$ in the body. Please edit out this self-intersection :)

Comment: Apologies! Fixed

Comment: If there is a self-intersection, the curve given by this short Weierstrass equation isn't smooth at that point, which means it is not an elliptic curve. As to finding an exact expression for $b$, do you know about the discriminant? And Cardano's formula?

Comment: Forgive me, for I don't know enough about elliptic curves to say whether this curve is smooth or not, or whether that makes it an elliptic curve or not. I also do not know about thee discriminant.

Comment: Okay, a curve such as this is 'smooth' at any given point if there is a well-defined tangent line. However, as you can probably see, a curve cannot be smooth at a self-intersection, because there are two 'tangent lines' here. Now, the discriminant of a curve $y^2=x^3+ax+b$ is the number $\Delta:=-16(4a^3+27b^2)$. The curve is smooth everywhere if and only if $\Delta\neq 0$. In case $\Delta=0$, there are two situations: Either we have a 'cusp' or a self-intersection. Which of the $2$ it is, you can read off an invariant of the curve called '$c_4$'. If I have more time, I'll write an answer

Comment: To get you started, $y^2 = (x-p)^2 (x-q) = x^3 - (2p+q)x^2 + (2pq+p^2)x-p^2q$

We have $2p+q = 0 \implies q = - 2p$. So, $2pq + p^2 = - 3p^2, -p^2q = 2p^3$

That leads to $y^2 = x^3 -3p^2 x +2p^3$

Comment: @MathLover you should make that an answer.

Comment: Your number is $\frac{2}{3 \sqrt{3}}$

Comment: @CameronWilliams thanks for the suggestion. I added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^3-x+b$ and consider the curve $y^2=f(x)$.

To say that the curve "self-intersects" at $(x_0,0)$  means $f$ has a double zero at $x_0$ : $f(x_0)=f'(x_0)=0$ and $f"(x_0)\neq 0$. (And because we work with the real numbers, $y^2=f(x)\ge 0$ near $x_0$)

If $x_0$ is such a double zero, then near we have the taylor expansion $f(x)=\frac{f''(x_0)}{2}(x-x_0)^2 + O((x-x_0)^2)=3x_0(x-x_0)^2 + O((x-x_0)^2)$. Therefore $x_0>  0$

Next, $f'(x)=3x^2-1$ so $x_0= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$.

Finally $f(x_0)=0\Longleftrightarrow b- \frac{2\sqrt{3}}{9}=0$

So  $$b=\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{9}$$

Comment: If it is $y^2 = x^3 - x + b$, $b$ cannot be negative for self intersecting curve.

Comment: I think after you find possible values of $b$, you can show RHS in factor form and show why negative $b$ will not have a solution.

Comment: @MathLover, thanks but i think I found another way.

Comment: yes sure. Basically you have $y^2 = (x + \frac{1}{\sqrt3})^{2} (x - \frac{2}{\sqrt3})$. But $x$ cannot be $\lt \frac{2}{\sqrt3}$.

Answer (score 4):

For the curve to be self intersecting, we take the form

$y^2 = (x-p)^2 (x-q) = x^3 - (2p+q)x^2 + (2pq+p^2)x-p^2q \ $. Please note that the curve forms only for $x \geq q$

As $x^2$ term is zero, $2p+q = 0 \implies q = - 2p$.

So, $2pq + p^2 = - 3p^2, -p^2q = 2p^3$

We also note that if $p \lt 0, q \gt 0$ but $x$ must be $\geq q$ so there is no solution (self-intersecting curve) for $p \lt 0$. Also when $p = 0, q = 0$ and so there is no solution for $p = 0$ either.

That leads to,

$y^2 = x^3 -3p^2 x +2p^3, p \gt 0$

Comment: Now if $3p^2 = 1, p = \frac{1}{\sqrt3}$ and $b = 2p^3 = \frac{2}{3\sqrt3}$

Comment: I prefer this answer because it works without the need for calculus. Given that elliptic curves are algebraic objects, an algebraic solution makes the most sense. It also has more generality.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I completely understand your point. While I did not do in this case, I am myself often guilty of turning to calculus too soon :)

Comment: I'm missing the condition $x \geq q$ point. Also note that the $\Delta = 0$

Comment: @kelalaka in $y^2 = (x-p)^2 (x-q)$, LHS is square of $y$ and hence RHS also cannot be negative. So the curve forms only for values of $x \geq q$.